# How to "Show .XML data into each column of listView1" ? C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, xml

I have a code in C# Windows Forms, which adding a datas & save there into .XML File.. How can i Coding in "..File1_Load.."`for adding .xml datas into each column of "listView1"` when i push START in program.

```
namespace WFApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ?????
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox4.Text);
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill ALL fields!", "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                int phone = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please write ONLY numbers in 'Phone' field!", "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox3.Clear();
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(textBox4.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please write ONLY mail address in 'E-mail' field!", "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox4.Clear();
                return;
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            var vItem = listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1];
            if (!File.Exists("XmlAddedDatas.xml"))
            {
                XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
                xmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("XmlAddedDatas.xml", xmlWriterSettings))
                {
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("People");
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Person");
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("FirstName", vItem.SubItems[0].Text + " ");
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LastName", vItem.SubItems[1].Text + " ");
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PhoneNumber", vItem.SubItems[2].Text + " ");
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Email", vItem.SubItems[3].Text + " ");
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                    xmlWriter.Flush();
                    xmlWriter.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("XmlAddedDatas.xml");
                XElement root = xDocument.Element("People");
                IEnumerable<XElement> rows = root.Descendants("Person");
                XElement firstRow = rows.Last();
                firstRow.AddAfterSelf(
                   new XElement("Person",
                   new XElement("FirstName", vItem.SubItems[0].Text + " "),
                   new XElement("LastName", vItem.SubItems[1].Text + " "),
                   new XElement("PhoneNumber", vItem.SubItems[2].Text + " "),
                   new XElement("Email", vItem.SubItems[3].Text + " ")));
                xDocument.Save("XmlAddedDatas.xml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really required to use a custom XmlWriter? Why don't you use the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) class? (Create an object which holds all data and just serialize it to an XML file)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then you can simply load an XML file by using:

```cs
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("path_of_xml_file_to_load");
```

Whereas xmlDoc then contain your xml document. You can then loop the content of the XML file by e.g.

```cs
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("whatever");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  string strItem = node.Value.ToString(); // And then add the value..
  lvi.SubItem.Add(strItem);
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, then I would like to have the question further elaborated.